# html() function with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm attempting to inject some html code with variables in it into a JQM UL Listview. The problem I am running into is it seems the variables are throwing off the code because when I remove them, it injects the HTML perfectly.

Here is the snippet:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#vendorMessages", function() {
    var listView = "";
    pubnub.subscribe(
        {
        channelGroup: getChannelGroup()
        },
        function (status, response) {
            alert("test");
            console.log(status, response);
        }
    );

    pubnub.channelGroups.listChannels(
        {
            channelGroup: getChannelGroup()
        }, 
        function (status, response) {
            response.channels.forEach( function (channel) {
                var channelFormatted = String(channel).split("_");
                var channelMember = channelFormatted[1];
                var temp = "<li onClick='loadChannel("+channel+")'>"+channelMember+"</li>";
                var temp = String(temp);
                listView = listView.concat(temp);
            })
            alert(listView);
        }
    )
    var elem = $("#channels");
    elem.html(elem.text(listView));
    $("#channels").listview("refresh");
})
```

The `alert(listView)` returns the correct string format but the code still will not get added to the `<ul>`. I've tried a few suggested things, even switching back to javascript innerHTML but no avail. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
elem.html(elem.text(listView));
```

to

```
elem.html(listView);
```

elem.text cannot handle html..

Comment: So I did this and still nothing. I feel like there is something wrong with `var temp = "<li onClick='loadChannel("+channel+")'>"+channelMember+"</li>";` because if I simply remove the variables everything is fine. Is there another way to put the variables in there?

Comment: could it be working but this line refreshes and removes the value? `$("#channels").listview("refresh");`

Comment: Just tried that, no change. Was something I had not considered though!

Comment: can you just put those end 3 lines where your alert is? maybe the function has not yet finished received a response..

Comment: That does not seem to fix it either.

Comment: How could that be? I thought the alert had the correct string? Does `#channels` exist? spelled correctly?